# Whatsapp backup and restore not working (Tested both local and google drive) - Bluestacks

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluestacks

How to do a whatsapp local backup and how to restore whatsapp using local backup.

I followed the steps mentioned in [https://www.business-standard.com/article/technology/how-to-back-up-restore-whatsapp-chat-history-using-google-drive-storage-119072500591_1.html#:~:text=To%20find%20the%20local%20backup,folder%20inside%20the%20WhatsApp%20folder](https://www.business-standard.com/article/technology/how-to-back-up-restore-whatsapp-chat-history-using-google-drive-storage-119072500591_1.html#:%7E:text=To%20find%20the%20local%20backup,folder%20inside%20the%20WhatsApp%20folder).

```
How to restore WhatsApp backup using microSD card

If you remove WhatsApp for any reason and install it again on the same device, the instant messenger notifies about the existing local backup and takes your permission to restore messages from it. Follow the steps below in case you switch to a new device and seek to restore WhatsApp chat history from local backup:

Step 1: Insert a microSD card in your old phone, if it has a slot

Step 2: Go to the phone’s file manager

Step 3: In the file manager, locate WhatsApp folder in root

Step 4: Copy the WhatsApp folder and transfer it to the microSD card

Step 5: Eject the microSD card safely and insert it in your new phone, if there is a slot

Step 6: Download and install WhatsApp on a new phone. Set it up and then uninstall it

Step 7: Replace the WhatsApp folder in your phone’s internal storage with the one saved in the microSD card

Step 8: In the file manager, navigate to sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases

Step 9: Rename the backup file you want to restore from msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt12 to msgstore.db.crypt12. It is possible that an earlier backup may be on an earlier protocol, such as crypt9 or crypt10. Don't change the number of the crypt extension

Step 10: Download and install WhatsApp again and select the option to restore the whatsapp data from "Google drive". But this time it will identify your local backup and notify if you would like to restore from it instead of visiting Google drive.

In case the old phone or the new phone does not have a microSD card slot, copy the WhatsApp folder from your phone’s internal storage on a desktop. Perform the step 6 mentioned above before transferring the folder in the new phone’s internal storage. Once you transfer the folder, perform Step 8 and onwards.
```

I have an Android device (actually I am using Bluestacks Android emulator but I expect the process to be the same). I have setup WhatsApp on this device. Now I want to move to another device. So I did a whatsapp local backup using `WhatsApp -> settings -> Chat backup -> Backup`

Now I manually copied the WhatsApp folder in the Andoid file system which has the folders Backups, Databases, Media

Now I manually transferred these folders and then installed Whatsapp on new Android device using the same phone number. But when I open Whatsapp in this new device, then I only see the option to restore from Google drive backup but not from local backup. So I clicked Skip but then I dont see my chats

What is the process to successfully backup and restore whatsapp data locally using Android emulator?

Edit:
I think there is an issue with the Whatsapp backup I am using. For example, the Whatsapp folder that was restored from Google drive is detected properly by whatsapp when I copied it to local storage. But the Whatsapp backup that I copied from Bluestacks is not detected I dont know why

Edit2:
I have opened whatsapp from my old Bluestacks device and backed up all whatsapp data to Google drive. Now in the new Bluestacks device I selected the Google drive account to restore the backup. But whatsapp is still not able to restore my chats etc. So this is probably a Bluestacks issue where I am not able to move the whatsapp backup from one device to another if I am using whatsapp on Bluestacks

So it looks like the whatsapp backup taken from an Android phone can be imported into Bluestacks. But the whatsapp backup taken from Bluestacks is not detected anywhere so I will loose the chat history, but atleast media is available in the whatsapp folders which I copied from my old Bluestacks device's Android file explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tested both local manual transfer and Google drive and found that the whatsapp data backedup from `Bluestacks` is not working for restore

But atleast I found that `nox`(used the version 3.0.3.0) app player Android emulator works fine. I tested the whatsapp backup and restore using Google drive and local manual transfer and both work fine

Additionally if one wants to know how to
Transfer files from nox Android emulator to MAC and vice versa,

```
Enable Root access in nox app player by selecting settings icon at top right corner of the nox app -> Switch ON the root. Then there is a common share folder which is accessible from both MAC and also nox Android emulator,

In nox the common share folder is at:- Open the Amaze File Manager (Tools folder on nox app player Android emulator home screen -> Amaze) and go to /root/mnt/shared 

In MAC the common share folder is at:- Go to /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/NoxAppPlayer/Nox_share

Now to transfer files from nox to MAC:-
From Phone(/Storage or /emulated/storage/0) folder if we want to copy something to /root folder(Accessible to both Phone and MAC) then we can only copy files (or zip files as well) and not folders so zip the whatsapp folder (using AstroFileExplorer+Winzip software because somehow winzip is not detected in Amaze File Manager) and copy the zip file from /Storage to /root/mnt/shared using Amaze File Manager

Then in MAC we will have the files already at the common share folder location
```

P.S:
The issue I have with nox Android emulator is that it does not detect the MAC touchpad scrolling. I need to click on screen using mouse cursor and then scroll the screen like a touch screen. https://www.reddit.com/r/noxappplayer/comments/g1qp7b/touchpad_on_macbook_pro_with_nox/

Also nox app player is not able to access the camera. So I cannot open web whatsapp for example because I need to scan a photo of the barcode using whatsapp app with a camera
https://www.reddit.com/r/noxappplayer/comments/bmv8pl/problem_cant_connect_to_camera/